# Reading entities intended sql query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a system where the customer wants to rework the current model so that everytime a user makes a change an administrator must accept the change before its written to the database..

I was thinking of doing a quick fix for this by overriden SaveChanges and taking each object in the ObjectStateManager and adding its intended sql code to a limbo table that would keep the inteded sql query saved until an admin has accepted it (and then run it).

I know that you can use ToTraceString() on database querys, but can you somehow pull the intended sql query on the object taken from ObjectStateManager?

Was thinking something like this:

```
var modified = DB.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

        foreach (var mod in modified)
        {

            //Insert the query to the limbo table         
            tblPendingChanges change = new tblPendingChanges();

            //Code omitted
            change.sql = mod.Query;
            //Code omitted
            DB.tblPendingChanges.AddObject(change);

            mod.Delete();

        }
DB.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: how about adding an 'IsApproved' flag to each entity....set it to false when a user edits an entity; and possibly prevent further edits until approved by admin...

Comment: hmm, well would cause some problems since a user can add addresses/persons etc to their profile that are relations. And be able to first change name or email, save and then something else.

Comment: funny: I don't see that requirement in original question...

Comment: well its kinda built into the solution, each entity change should be sent to the pedingchanges table (accepts are executed after date submitted). So if a user first faulty commits a change to his email and then right after commits a correction both would be submitted and executed so that the last commit would be the final result.

Comment: I have researched but came up empty, thats why I ask. And I dont think I should be boring everyone who tries to help me with a long intro on what i've already thought about. If you dont have any constructive information please leave the question instead of doing a useless downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using a entity wrapper found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32)

This allowed me to read each sql statement before it was sent to the server. Redirecting it.

I had to edit the wrapper to allow parameters to be inserted correctly into the statement so that the sql statement could be run.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is terrible. If you have the requirement that each change must be approved it leads to approval workflow where you save changes to some temporary store and move them to the main tables once approved. It is really not done on SQL level. If you need something working on SQL level don't use high level tools like Entity framework because they are really not designed to support this. For example EF will not provide you SQL commands generated for data modifications.

Comment: What would you recommend then? The system isn't updated much when it comes to the data it contains, but the data is really sensetive so it has to be checked by an admin before pushed to the live tables(which other system use aswell). I have been looking on ef tracing wrappers and have gotten the sql command in plain text working. But if you have a better solution for me please elaborate.

Comment: Simply you will not force EF to "not save data". Either not use EF or redesign your application to store changes separately and add another administrator UI where admin will approve changes and they will be saved to main tables.

Comment: "store changes separately" could u please elaborate? Say i have a customer with a tblAdress relation. The address is modified.. But since its the actual billingaddress the system needs the admin to check that the address is valid..